# camera2 capture image different with preview

Tags: android, jpeg, android-camera2

my capture picture output not same with my camera preview in landscape mode

1. before cpture
   [image: before capture]
2. after capture

[image: after capture]

whats wrong ? and whats have i do.  thanks

Comment: Show your code then we can help

Comment: @PhátPhát i dot know why if i put my code in ask stackoverflow that can post cause some error, so this is my code to capture and preview in camera 2

https://gist.github.com/yudikarma/5e473b3c42787bdd7acde327b89c10a2

Comment: Can you please help me double check 2 things: 1. Test on another device. 2. Please upload code of `AutoFitTextureView` which extends `TextureView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `AutoFitTextView` class which I pulled from Google sample. You can take a look at [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/AutoFitTextureView.java). It aims to show **camera view** and config the ratio base on the physical size of device.

```
public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {

    private int mRatioWidth = 0;
    private int mRatioHeight = 0;

    // Some codes here...

    public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
        }
        mRatioWidth = width;
        mRatioHeight = height;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
                setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
            } else {
                setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2 points in this class:

1. **You can't ensure the ratio works properly in every device**. However, we are able to choose optimized size which is already defined in this [class](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java).
2. **This condition is wrong:** `if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight)`. It should be *>* because when width is bigger than height, we calculate and set measure dimension base on width (not height).

**UPDATED**

If you just want every device will work properly in a particular ratio, then set hard ratio for it (for instance: 4/3)

You can achieve that by replacing those lines of code:

```
mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                        rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                        maxPreviewHeight, largest);

-> previewSize = Size(4, 3)
```

Comment: i was change < to > but image output keep bigger than preview. if you know how to set ration 4:3 preview please help me

Comment: Which device are you testing on? Can you print the value of mRatioHeight and mRatioWidth?

Comment: I updated the code for the ratio, please take a look @Yudikarma

Comment: How about the progress ^^ Did you make it?

Comment: thats make camera preview bad resolution and capture image keep bigger than camera2 preview

Comment: Please let me know which device are you use to testing or upload your code (snippet of your library) then I can help further.

Comment: this is my AutofitTextureVIew class : https://gist.github.com/yudikarma/68fce54cc17ec62915920ad682d1815b

Comment: i think  if i crop image to fit just like my preview, how to get the area just like camera preview to crop use CaptureRequest.set(CaptureRequest.SCALLER_CROP_REGION, [Rect of area preview])

Comment: please read my question this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957388/camera2-api-issue