# Camera2 API Issue

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

I make some camera App use camera2 APi example camera2 api google sample,
so my camera output not full screen

[image: Autofit texture view not full screen]

then i read from camera2 api isue to solve that i have to change this in Onmeasure at AUtofitTextureView class:

```
if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
```

from < to >
so like here :

```
 if (width > height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
```

then my camera view fix to fullscreen 
[image: camera preview full scren]

but Now i have other issue,
my capture image is bigger than my preview.

please check my screen capture from my app

1. my camera preview not full screen

[image: sdsds]

2. my capture image if camera preview not full screen

[image: sdsdds]
3. my camera preview  Full screen after change on Meisure method

[image: sdsdsd]

4. my capture image from camera preview after change on Meisure method.
   [image: dsssdds]

the problem is that make my capture image not same with my camera preview

Comment: paste your `xml`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/yudikarma/f1d1f1e688cad47e270ea720ea1c0a91 @Ali

Comment: i mean how to crop image and make that output JPEG same with preview . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried by the following way, here is shared my code for maintaining the aspect ratio of 16:9,18:9,19:9.hope this answer will help,  based on the device resolution choice ArrayList have max to min resolution this is the way I resolve the preview stretch issue.

```
//Samsung-S6-choices[0]
//Samsung-S7-edge-choices[6]
//OnePlus-5T-choices[15]
/*
 * Given {@code choices} of {@code Size}s supported by a camera, chooses the smallest one whose
 * width and height are at least as large as the respective requested values, and whose aspect
 * ratio matches with the specified value.
 *
 * @param choices     The list of sizes that the camera supports for the intended output class
 * @param width       The minimum desired width
 * @param height      The minimum desired height
 * @param aspectRatio The aspect ratio
 * @return The optimal {@code Size}, or an arbitrary one if none were big enough
 */
private  Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height, Size aspectRatio) {
    // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
    int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
    double ratio = (double) h / w;
    int loopCounter=0;
    for (Size size : choices) {
        int orientation = getActivityContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && size.getWidth() <=720) {
            //if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && size.getWidth() <=3840 ) {
            //if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && size.getWidth() <=5120 ) {//Retina 5K
            if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && size.getWidth() <=7680 ) {//8K UHDTV Super Hi-Vision
                Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size);
                return size;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:--given--"+size);
            DisplayMetrics metrics = getActivityContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            float mCameraAspectRatio = ((float)metrics.heightPixels / (float)metrics.widthPixels);
            Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:--AspectRatio--"+mCameraAspectRatio);
            if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && ((size.getWidth() <=1280)||(size.getHeight()<=1920))) {
                //if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && (size.getWidth() <=4320 ) ) {//8K UHDTV Super Hi-Vision
                //if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && (size.getWidth() <=2880 ) ) {//Retina 5K
                //if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && (size.getWidth() <=2160 ) ) {
                //if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && (size.getWidth() <=1280 ) ) {
                //if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && (size.getWidth() <=4480 && size.getWidth() >=1280) ) {
                Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size+"-16:9");
                return size;
            }else if((size.getWidth()/18) == (size.getHeight()/9) && ((size.getWidth() <=3840)||(size.getHeight()<=2160))) {
                Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size+"-18:9");
                return size;
            }else if((size.getWidth()/18.5) == (size.getHeight()/9) && ((size.getWidth() <=3840)||(size.getHeight()<=2160))) {
                Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size+"-18.5:9");
                return size;
            }else if((size.getWidth()/19) == (size.getHeight()/9) && ((size.getWidth() <=3840)||(size.getHeight()<=2160))) {
                Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size+"-19:9");
                return size;
            }else if((size.getWidth()/19.5) == (size.getHeight()/9) && ((size.getWidth() <=3840)||(size.getHeight()<=2160))) {
                Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size+"-19.5:9");
                return size;
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize"+" not proper aspect resolution");
                Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize"+" ---=>Width---=>"+size.getWidth());
                Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize"+" ---=>Height---=>"+size.getHeight());
            }
            //2340
        }

        if(screenWidth==size.getWidth()){
            Log.e(TAG1, loopCounter+".choose:width Matched:"+screenWidth+"="+size.getWidth());
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG1, loopCounter+".choose:width Not Matched:"+screenWidth+"="+size.getWidth());
        }

        if(screenHeight==size.getHeight()){
            Log.e(TAG1, loopCounter+".choose:height Matched:"+screenHeight+"="+size.getHeight());
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG1, loopCounter+".choose:height Not Matched:"+screenHeight+"="+size.getHeight());
        }
        loopCounter++;
    }
    // Pick the smallest of those, assuming we found any
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG1, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
        return choices[0];
    }
}


/*
 * Compares two {@code Size}s based on their areas.
 */
static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
        // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
        return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Hope it will help, please leave a comment, in case of any issue.